# Observe NSDate or Time in background of application to play custom sound as Alarm

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I am working on Prayer app which indicates prayer times. All i have to do now that if app is running or running in background. when prayer time reaches i want to play a sound with more then 60second. 
I am stuck with observing time in the background. Anyone please help me in this.

Comment: Simply, run a digital clock internally to observe the date/time in terms of total number of seconds since 1970.  And convert the target time to the number of total seconds.

Comment: @TBlue I need to set 5 Alrams for date.

Comment: Then you need 5 sets of target date and time.

Comment: @TBlue I have Done :) I am also thinking of proper tutorial for beginners too.

Comment: Amir, Could you tell me how you did it? I need the same as you. Thank you!

Comment: @mhergon skype me amir.ios

Answer (score 2):

iOS App will not run in the background for more than 10 minutes, unless it's music or lbs app.  However, you can use the UILocalNotification, the sound of a UILocalNotification can't be more than 30 seconds, so if you want a 60-second sounds, you need to schedule more than one UILocalNotification.

Comment: two UILocalNotification?? can you please guide how to.